# Undestanding for loop in pipe creation in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have a comprension question about this code that I am currently studying: this function is used in a C Shell implementation to execute piped commands. I can't understand how the person who wrote it got to know how many pipes to close (why is the limit `2*com- 2`)?

```
        for(i = 0; i < 2*com - 2; i++) close(pip[i]);
        for(i = 0; i < com; ++i) {
                waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
```

Comment: The number of pairs is one less than the commands because that's all that is needed. Consider two commands. How many pipe sets to you setup *between* them? Ans: one. What about three commands? Ans: two (one set between the first and second command, another between the second and third.

Comment: @Anna : Why is this question tagged by _shell_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this program, `num_pipe` is not actually the number of pipes
but the number of commands (very bad name indeed!).
Between two commands you need one pipe, between three commands
you need two pipes ... between N commands you need N-1 pipes.
Each pipe relies on two file descriptors (one for reading, one
for writing) thus `2*(num_pipe-1)` file descriptors are needed
for `num_pipe` commands.
note: the `malloc()` does not allocate *an array of integer pointers*
(as stated in the question) but an array of integers.

Following this logic, I would have written
`for(i = 0; i < 2*(num_pipe-1); i += 2)`
but `2*(num_pipe-1)` equals to `2*num_pipe-2` and since the step
is `2`, the loop condition is the same with the limit
`2*num_pipe-3`.
It's just terribly confusing in my opinion.